# IDIV in assembly isn't giving me the wanted result (NASM)

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to do a simple division:

```
mov ebx, 10
mov eax, 1111111111        ;(10 times)
mov edx, 0
idiv  bx
```

Supposedly I want to get the following results:

edx = 1

eax = 111111111   (9 times)

But the results I'm getting are:

edx = 7

eax = 1111098720

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any version of `IDIV` that accepts an immediate operand in Intel's manual. How are you assembling that code?

Comment: I'm not sure i understood your question but what I'm showing is just a part of a code

Comment: I'm saying that `idiv 10` is not a valid instruction according to Intel's manual, unless 10 is being interpreted as "some memory at address 10". So we need to know how you assemble this (i.e. which assembler are you using, have you defined any macros named `idiv`, etc?)

Comment: NASM (version 2.10.09) says _" error: invalid combination of opcode and operands"_.

Comment: Would you edit your question and add the tag "nasm"? And try moving "10" into a register, then replace "10" by the register in your "idiv" (like ecx).

Comment: Changed it but still won't work

Comment: @RoiAvram: since it was just a typo, this question should probably just get deleted.  I don't think it will be useful to anyone else in the future.  I think I have to delete my answer (since it has an upvote) for you to be able to delete your own question.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mov ebx, 10
> mov eax, 1111111111        ;(10 times)
> mov edx, 0
> idiv  bx
> ```

What immediately strikes me is that you setup all registers for **32**-bit operation but then perform a **16**-bit division.
Changing it to the following will give the desired results:

```
mov  ebx, 10
mov  eax, 1111111111
cdq
idiv ebx
```

Comment: he already solved his own problem; see the comment on my answer.  See the edit history; I was trying to stop other people wasting their time looking at this.  Should I have turned the question into a non-question by putting the solution as a comment on the code *in* the question?  Or just left it with the original `idiv ebx` which obviously isn't what he actually ran to produce those results?

Comment: @PeterCordes Noted. I admit I didn't read the whole edit history. I do think though that by your edit you effectively produced another question. The edit done by the OP (from `idiv 10` to `idiv ebx`) should not have been done either! I do like your suggestion to put a warning comment __in__ the question.

Comment: I don't want to bump it again with another edit; it just needs to be closed and deleted.