# What is signed division(idiv) instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, division, integer-division, signed-integer

In intel instruction, idiv(integer divsion) means signed division.
I got the result of `idiv`, but I don't quite understand the result.

***- Example***

```
0xffff0000 idiv 0xffff1100
```

***- My wrong prediction***
As long as I know, `quotient` should be 0, and `remainder` should be 0xffff0000 and because...

```
0xffff0000 / 0xffff1100 = 0  
0xffff0000 % 0xffff1100 = 0xffff0000
```

***- However, the result was...***
*Before `idiv`*

```
eax            0xffff0000            # dividend
esi            0xffff1100            # divisor
edx            0x0
```

*After `idiv`*

```
eax            0xfffeedcc            # quotient
edx            0x7400   29696        # remainder
```

***- Question***.
The result was value I couldn't expected.
Could someone explain about signed division(`idiv`)?

***- Appended.*** 
Here's More information about `idiv`.
`idiv` uses the eax register as a source register.
  As a result of execution, quotient is stored at eax, and remainder is stored at edx.

Comment: You say "8086 instruction" but then you use "eax" and "edx" which are not 8086 registers. Please clarify. Note also that the idiv instruction uses the (e)dx register as a source register, which you did not specify.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you for your advice. I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: @Jiwon - the question still doesn't show what is in edx before idiv.

Comment: Have you looked at something like [(idiv) IA-32 Assembly Language Reference Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3773/instructionset-44/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IDIV in assembly isn't giving me the wanted result (NASM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552056/idiv-in-assembly-isnt-giving-me-the-wanted-result-nasm)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`idiv` divides edx:eax by the explicit source operand.  See Intel's [instruction manual entry](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IDIV.html).

Since edx is 0, edx:eax is a positive number. You are dividing 4294901760 by -61184, giving -70196 with a remainder of 29696.

Remember that both dividend (EDX:EAX) and divisor (ESI in your case) are interpreted as 2's complement signed numbers, so any bit-pattern with the high bit set is negative.

```
00000000ffff0000 = 4294901760
ffff1100 = -61184
fffeedcc = -70196
7400 = 29696
```

You should sign extend eax into edx using `cdq` before using idiv, instead of zero-extending by zeroing EDX.

However, that still won't give the results you were expecting, because -65536 divided by -61184 equals 1 with a remainder of -4352.

---

(A negative dividend and positive divisor would give a negative remainder: [X86 IDIV sign of remainder depends on sign of dividend for 8/-3 and -8/3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53966486/x86-idiv-sign-of-remainder-depends-on-sign-of-dividend-for-8-3-and-8-3))

Comment: Man I was looking for an instruction like cdq like forever. I was stuck with testing the sign bit and storing 0xffff_ffff into edx.